# Scala Recursion and Units

Tags: scala, recursion, binary-tree

I am Implementing a basic binary tree in scala. I am implementing insert and I run into the issue that my recursive function is calling itself on a node that has not yet been initialized.

```
// binarytree.scala
sealed abstract class Tree {
  def insert(_value: Int)
}

case class Node(value: Int, left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree {
  def insert(_value: Int) =
    if (_value < value) Node(value, left.insert(_value), right)
    else Node(value, left, right.insert(_value))
}

case object End extends Tree {
  def insert(_value: Int) = Node(_value)
}

object Node {
 def apply(_value: Int): Node = Node(_value, End, End)
}

var bt = Node( 3 )
println(bt.insert(4))
```

My implementation uses End nodes to represent nodes that have not been instantiated yet. I thought this would avoid the exact error I am getting. Here is the error log for the left.insert():

```
error: type mismatch;
  found   : Unit
  required: this.Tree
    if (_value < value) Node(value, left.insert(_value), right)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to annotate the return type of insert in the Tree class:

```
sealed abstract class Tree {
  def insert(_value: Int) : Node
}
```

Its being inferred as having a return type of Unit now